# How to make a today widget of iOS8 automatically appear in today panel after host app is installed

Tags: ios, widget

My app contains a today widget. After installation of the app, the widget is not loaded by default. I must add it manually in edit area of Today widgets.

Is it possible to make the widget automatically appear after I install my app?

Answer (score 0):

No unfortunately this is not possible.